# Facebook comments plugin screams: Warning:URL unreachable

Tags: facebook

Please check www.turie.eu
It displays yellow box with Warning: http://www.turie.eu/ is unreachable. When you click on that url, it goes to facebook linter and displays:

```
Critical
Invalid app ID  ID application "{135765723173532}" specified in meta tag "fb:app_id" was invalid.
Error
Invalid app ID  ID application "{135765723173532}" specified in meta tag "fb:app_id" was invalid.
```

I'm absolutely sure that the ID is ok and the url is fine too. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have specified an app-id in your facebook settings. check the tag that says

`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{135765723173532}">`

and make sure the correct app id is specified in the 'content' property

Comment: Thank you, Timothy. That ID within the meta tag is exactly the same facebook gave me when I created FB app.

Comment: So, the problem was with the {}. They should not be there. I don't know why facebook include them in documentation. Now there is no warning on page and as administrator (interesting, that It doesn't work with one administrator, I have to add two of them) I can see administrator setting, but still not all of them. The message is:

    Cannot edit global settings or moderation mode without fb:app_id

fb:app_id is defined within the meta tag, but FB doesn't see it and I don't know why.

Comment: Facebook's documentation is flaky at best, i agree.
These meta tags are added to facebook's database when it actually crawls your site.
There is no real guarantee about how long this will take, or when it will happen.
Not until facebook has crawled the page, found and indexed and processed the meta tag will it work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook didn't seem to even acknowledge my meta tags, I don't know why, maybe because my page is build with several interchangeable panels.

Anyways, the problem with the new html5 box vanished in my app when I changed the data-href path to my fan page wall url. I don't know why, it's not even declared in my app settings, but that's what worked in my case. Facebook doesn't seem to have any problem at all when the url is a facebook url.